# aws ec2 "Blocked by X-Frame-Options Policy"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, x-frame-options

i'm redirect/forwarding (iframe) a domain registered at ionos.com to aws ec2 free tier hosted spring boot embedded tomcat java application so that people don't see the long url of ec2, I got error in firefox displaying "Blocked by X-Frame-Options Policy", it seems to be caused by aws ec2 policy. I wonder what is the simplest way to resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong, it is not aws ec2 causing this. it seems to be the spring default.

it was fixed by adding  http.headers().frameOptions().disable(); 
in MultipleEntryPointsSecurityConfig