# Why does a request to a single endpoint take 5 minutes on IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an ASP.NET MVC application running on IIS using .NET Framework 4.7.2. There is a single endpoint that takes 5 minutes to return a response. The response is successful and there is no error in the code or in the IIS logs.

I have timed almost every line in the controller action using `System.Diagnostic.Stopwatch` and the whole action finishes in under 100 milliseconds.

More interesting, we are running this application in AWS in both a staging and production environment account. This problem only occurs in the production environment and it is only a single server. We actually have two servers running a copy of this application, and it is only the one server that has this problem. While the server having the problem receives substantially more traffic than the other servers, it only receives approximately 25,000 page views per day and no other endpoint takes this long to fulfill the request.

The application is deployed using Elastic Beanstalk and the *.NET on Windows Server* platform. We have rebuilt the application environment and the server multiple times and it is consistent across servers.

I have also connected directly to the server and installed IIS Failed Request Tracing. According to IIS Failed Request Tracing, step 206. `GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER` where `HeaderName=X-Frame-Options` and `HeaderValue=SAMEORIGIN` took 362,063 milliseconds (~6 minutes). This is in the `ManagedPipelineHeader` module with notification `EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER`.

See Image: [IIS Failed Request Tracing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbmUD.png)

Comment: IIS FRT and your own application level logging successfully squeezed the issue to a narrow enough scope. The time was consumed by ASP.NET framework for some unknown reason, so you next step is to verify ASP.NET ETW https://www.tessferrandez.com/blog/2008/11/06/troubleshooting-appdomain-restarts-and-other-issues-with-ETW-tracing.html A few hang dumps of the worker process might also help. However, interpreting ETW or hang dumps can be difficult, so you probably should have someone with more experience by your side.

Comment: Hey Bryan you mentioned that it is one endpoint in specific that exhibits the delay, I realize only one environment.   Does that endpoint, as compared to the other controller actions, do any kind of outbound web request type of activity in order to service its requests?
(System.Net.Http or WebClient, etc)

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for the article. I will see if it can tell me anything more useful about what specifically is causing the request to take so long.

Comment: @BillD The one endpoint does not make any outbound connections. It verifies that a PDF form the user has uploaded is completed. The file is uploaded in a different step, so the endpoint isn't receiving a large request body.

Comment: @LexLi After following the article, I am left with an ETL file that log parser cannot parse. When attempting to parse the ETL file on the same server, I get that the trace file has been created on a OS Version (10) that is different from the current version. Opening the ETL file in Event Viewer does not help either. There is no information in the logs.

Comment: Does recycle work for you? You can use Network Monitor to capture traffic as requests are made.

Comment: @Bryan Did you get any more clarity on this? I'm seeing something similar, on ASP.NET MVC/.NET 4.7/AWS where GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER for 'Cache-Control' is taking >3 seconds (i realize it's not as exorbitant as your example :).

Comment: @ilasno Unfortunately, no. After several months, the problem just went away and we haven't had a problem with it since.

Answer (score 0):

Yikes, 6 minutes. I'm surprised it didn't time out. I noticed [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61715520/aws-ec2-blocked-by-x-frame-options-policy) but it didn't see directly relevant in that they were using Spring Boot and your app was ASP.Net MVC 4x.  It does make me wonder, though if there isn't a shared underlying cause.    So in their case they disabled frameoptions in spring boot (http.headers().frameOptions().disable()) via config so that it would stop trying to write that request header.

In both cases, hard to tell without poking around but I'm wondering if CloudFront and the particular framework in each example aren't fighting for dominance over this particular header but you didn't mention Cloudfront so I might be completely off.   Any chance of Cloudfront being used on your prod side (with the issue) and not the dev side?

Comment: This is not a qualified answer, as you didn't point out what's wrong.

Comment: Fair but its an honest attempt to give the Bryan a research path, if the prod environment includes Cloudfront in the stack or any app load balancer for that matter as would be pretty common in a prod vs non-prod env, then those services will endeavor to rewrite the headers according to maybe-not-obvious policies in that  AWS service stack.  I guess I could have just told him to get more experience, like you did.

Comment: The staging and production environments match very closely. A request goes through an WAF maintained by an outside team before hitting our AWS ALB and then being sent straight to the server. The only difference between the two environments is that the production servers are a bigger EC2 instance.